# Tensorflow 2.4 can't load libraries on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, tensorflow2.0

1. I have installed CUDA 11.2 with cudnn11.1 into the environment of Visual Studio
2. I have also installed NVIDIA GPU drivers
3. I have also make an environment directory for CUDA

When I start a TensorFlow program, I'm receiving this output with an error. How to resolve it?

```
2021-01-14 17:17:51.021072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:07.957368: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-14 17:18:07.999047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:08.076797: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.515GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-01-14 17:18:08.088920: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:08.521603: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:08.521714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:08.802118: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:08.830919: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
**2021-01-14 17:18:08.831508: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found**
2021-01-14 17:18:09.020120: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:09.035560: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-14 17:18:09.035647: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
```

Skipping the part with registering of GPU devices...

```
2021-01-14 17:18:09.141469: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2

To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-14 17:18:09.144203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:

2021-01-14 17:18:09.144292: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      
2021-01-14 17:18:09.144353: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-14 17:18:09.988775: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

Running `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

```
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2021-01-15 09:25:19.220025: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-15 09:25:19.226960: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:19.274956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.515GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-01-15 09:25:19.278653: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:19.725636: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:19.727467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:20.019647: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:20.051902: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:20.055165: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-01-15 09:25:20.251482: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:20.270073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-15 09:25:20.272694: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Comment: cusolver64_10.dll not found

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44291 you seem to.be using a buggy version of tensorflow. Use conda or go back to a more stable version.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Bug with the current version of TensorFlow + CUDA,

```
**2021-01-14 17:18:08.831508: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found**
```

You can see from this line, it tries to search for `cusolver64_10.dll` even though you are using 11.

Please go to,

`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin`

and make a copy of the file called `cusolver64_11.dll` and paste it in the same directory. Then rename it to `cusolver64_10.dll`.

This should fix it, but currently, the latest stable version of TensorFlow is not built against CUDA 11.2, to get the best performance I will recommend downgrading to [CUDA 11.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive) and [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) 8.0.4 (please go to archives and select cuDNN v8.0.4 for CUDA 11.0).

This would provide you with the best stability and performance, as I see that you're not using an Ampere card.

Comment: from my experience, it is better to copy paste the cusolver64_10.dll from Cuda 10.2 bin directory to the Cuda Bin one instead of doing what you suggested.